# inserting a string that looks like a date to a database date column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, date

im having a problam inserting a string that looks like a date (23.02.2015)
from datagridview to my local database date column that .

i know i need to transfer my string "23.02.2015" to 23/02/2015 and convert it to a date variable before im inserting it to my database date column but i dont know how to do it inside my code :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project\Project\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
                {

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ResultsTable VALUES(@Date, @TagNumber)", con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", row.Cells["Exposure Date"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagNumber", row.Cells["Device #"].Value);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();     
                    }


                }
            }

        MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");

    }
```

in short - im having a problam to convert a string like "23.05.2014" to a date type like 23/05/2014 to insert it to date column in my database in my code .

Comment: Do you want something like `Convert.ToDateTime(Regex.Replace(input, ".", "/"))` to convert string automatically into datetime before inserting?

Comment: yes ! but where in my code im inserting this line to fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you if your string date is always in the given format. [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

```
string smdt = row.Cells["Exposure Date"].Value;
//This is the string format which is going to parse the Date
string format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(smdt, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

and then

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dt);
```

Comment: thanks ! works fine now !!

Comment: Happy to help @shlezz :) Happy Coding Kudos

Answer (score -2):

Please try below code:

```
string stringDate = "23.02.2015";  // Hold your string date here (row.Cells["Exposure Date"].Value)
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will convert your string date (stringDate) to a datetime (date) object, and you can pass this **date** object to stored procedure parameter.

I believe, you are always getting string date in this ("dd.MM.yyyy") format. Else, you will need to change it as per your string format.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: How is it different from my answer??

Comment: I just saw, you posted same answer.. moreover, about 7-8 minutes before mine. So, it is simple to think.. I just modified your answer and re-posted.

But believe me my friend, this was not the case.. actually when I found this question.. there was not a single answer but I took it more than 10 minutes (not sure but possibly got a Skype call that time) to post my answer and without REFRESHING the window and then I am seeing this today. 

Sorry.